# Powershell to Add an owner to O365 group failing

Tags: powershell

Trying to run a seemingly simple Set-Group command and it's failing and I have no idea why. In the Set-Group Technet page it says the below...

> To add or remove owners without affecting other existing entries, use the following syntax: @{Add="owner1","owner2"...; Remove="owner3","owner4"...}.

But when running the below it fails...

```
set-group -Identity "O365Group" -ManagedBy @{Add="User1","User2"}
```

Fails with this error...

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ManagedBy'. Cannot
>   convert value "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralRecipientIdParameter[]". Error:
>   "Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralRecipientIdParameter". Error:
>   "Cannot convert hashtable to an object of the following type:
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralRecipientIdParameter.
>   Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in restricted language mode or
>   a Data section.""
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Group], ParameterBindin...
>      mationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-Group
>       + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: Are you using UPN for `User1` and `User2` and so forth? If not, I would suggest using that, as I find a lot of O365 cmdlet, say they support `SamAccountName`, but it always messes up, and UPN always have worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried with email address and UPN

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: On powershell version 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an Office 365 Group, you might want to use the *-unifiedgrouplinks commandlets.

```
#note to add an owner, they have to be a member first
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity groupUPN@groups.contso.com -LinkType Member -Links upn@contoso.com
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity groupUPN@groups.contso.com -LinkType Owner -Links upn@contoso.com
Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity groupUPN@groups.contso.com -LinkType Owner -Links upn2@contoso.com
```

So if I wanted to add UPN1@contso.com,UPN2@contso.com,UPN3@contso.com as owner to myFanClub@groups.contoso.com I would run the following from an Exchange Online Powershell session

```
"UPN1@contso.com","UPN2@contso.com","UPN3@contso.com"|%{
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity myFanClub@groups.contoso.com -LinkType Member -Links $_
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity myFanClub@groups.contoso.com -LinkType Owner -Links $_
#If you want to subscribe them as well, uncomment this line
#Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity myFanClub@groups.contoso.com -LinkType subscriber -Links $_
}
```

More information on these commandlets can be found here:

Remove-unifiedgrouplinks : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238271(v=exchg.160).aspx

Add-UnifiedGroupLinks : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238269(v=exchg.160).aspx

Get-UnifiedGroupLinks : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238273(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: Yeah I saw this yesterday but thought it was a bit strange that they needed to be added as members to make them owners. Doesn't really explain why Set-Group doesn't work as intended even though it says you're able to do it on the Technet article.

Comment: @JimThomas I found a lot of TechNet articles that say something suppose to do things a certain way but in reality it doesn't. I'm guessing the documentation is not up to date, or a regression issue.

Comment: Looks like Set-Group only works for Distribution groups/mail enabled security groups. While O365 groups are similar, it is still broken out (Kind of like how set-dynamicdistributiongroup is)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Set-Group`, use `Set-DistributionGroup` instead.

`Set-DistributionGroup -Identity "O365Group" -ManagedBy @{Add="User1","User2"}`

I've tested this on our Office 365 deployment, where `Set-Group` fails, `Set-DistributionGroup` works without any errors.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, I tried that as well when I was troubleshooting. If I do Get-DistributionGroup "O365Group" it doesn't return any results. Have to use Get-Group to return it.

Comment: That's very odd, and you're using the UPN for the `O365Group`?

Comment: Not for the O365 Group no, there's no such parameter (that I can see) for that.

When running "get-group "O365Group" | fl" it doesn't have a UPN option on there. I always just use the display name for the actual groups.

Comment: Totally missed that. Perhaps you have to go through MSOnline or AzureAD cmdlets then.